# Google Dialogflow not returning correct Date-Period

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am having an issue with Date-Period Entity in a Google Dialogflow Agent that I recently created.

So I have a @sys.date-period Entity in my intent. And suppose the current month is "July" and current year is "2020". When I ask for a month that has already passed like "June,May ... january", dialogflow returns date-period with year "2021". However, when I ask for the current month or a month that has yet to come like "july, august ... december", dialogflow returns the correct year which is "2020".

It is quite annoying and there is nothing mentioned to solve such a problem in their documentation.

**NOTE: I do not specify the year in my query, I simply say the name of month. In return, I want it to detect the correct year which is the current year.**

Comment: if you specify last year/month, this year/month, next year/month DF will understand that. If you do not specify, how do you expect a computer to know which year/month you are talking about? The default feature makes perfect sense to me, but if you want to interpret it differently you should write your own logic either by asking the user to specifiying or using fulfillment to change the default.

Comment: @Ghulam Mustufa Are you assuming that the default date (year/month/day) for sys.date-period Entity should be according to when you set it up, cause Gray_Rhino's comment above is correct.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino Thanks for the suggestion. You are correct that using fulfillment is the only logical way to change the interpretation of a system entity. I actually thought that I am missing something in my implementation but I was wrong and was implementing my agent correctly. I need to use fulfillment now i think. Thanks again :)